# Visual Studio Code doesn't stop on Python breakpoint debug

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code on Windows 10, I installed the Python extension to allow completion, debugging,...
I had previously installed python 2.7.

When I try to debug a very easy script (2 print, 1 if, 1 variable assignation) after putting breakpoints, it doesn't stop, the script is executed like there was no breakpoint.

I let the default pythonPath in launch.json and settings.json, and it uses the one in PATH which is the one I want to use, so no problem. I do not use any virtualenv.

Do you have any clue?
Thanks

EDIT : Here the code (> marks the lines with breakpoints)

```
>import sys
>if 1 == 1:
   >print "test"
>test= 'yes'
print "yesyes"
```

Comment: How about showing us your code and indicating where your breakpoints are

Comment: yeah ok done, hope this helps...

Comment: Hi Rapha, I'm the author of this extension. Please could you create an issue on github so I could help you with this. FYI - I am unable to replicate this at my end. https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/issues

Comment: https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/issues/348 I will update this thread

Comment: was this fixed? happens to me as well

Comment: Yep, I put the file in the Scripts directory inside the Python27 folder, all files must be placed in a non related python directory!

Comment: @Rapha I have the same issue and find this post. I put my script under Python27 folder too. If I put it under another folder the breakpoints can work. Where did you get the information that "all files must be placed in a non related python directory"?

Answer (score 2):

In case it is relevant for anyone: in my case breakpoints were not hit due to a remnant piece of code I used for remote debugging using `ptvsd`:

`ptvsd.enable_attach()`

Removing this solved this issue while debugging using `launch.json` for me.

Note: in the OP's case the problem was that they put their code in the `C:\Python27\Scripts` folder, which should not be done.